# Cloud Function Not Working

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I want to add notifications to an online android chatting app I have made. I am new to cloud functions, so I tried using the code given here https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html

---

My index.js file

```
var firebase = require('firebase-admin');
var request = require('request');

var API_KEY = "xyz"; // Your Firebase 
Cloud Messaging Server API key

// Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
var serviceAccount = require("firebase.json");

// Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
firebase.initializeApp({
credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://firebaseio.com/"
});
ref = firebase.database().ref();

function listenForNotificationRequests() {
var requests = ref.child('notificationRequests');
requests.on('child_added', function(requestSnapshot) {
var request = requestSnapshot.val();
sendNotificationToUser(
  request.username, 
  request.message,
  function() {
      console.log('notificationrecived, sent and removed- ' + 
request.username + '  '+ request.message,);
    requestSnapshot.ref.remove();
  }
 );
 }, function(error) {
  console.error(error);
 });
 };

 function sendNotificationToUser(username, message, onSuccess) {
 request({
 url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
 method: 'POST',
 headers: {
  'Content-Type' :' application/json',
  'Authorization': 'key='+API_KEY
 },
 body: JSON.stringify({
  notification: {
    title: message
  },
  to : '/topics/'+username
  })
  }, function(error, response, body) {
  if (error) { console.error(error); }
  else if (response.statusCode >= 400) { 
  console.error('HTTP Error: '+response.statusCode+' - ' 
  +response.statusMessage); 
     }
    else {n
    onSuccess();
   }
  }); 
  }

  // start listening
  listenForNotificationRequests();
```

I have successfully deployed this code to the server using node.js command line.
But this does not show up on the console and nor the logs that I added to debug 
and the code doesn't seem to work. I have done everything given in the link i mentioned. I could use some help on how to fix my code

Comment: Hi Chirag. What exactly isn't working? Is it throwing an error?

Comment: nope, no error at all. it just doesn't respond to any changes in the database

Comment: also the deploy shows successful  in node.js command line but no deploy is shown  in firbase console

Comment: Might be something with how you're accessing the DB on your client side. It would help if you post it as well.

Comment: thanks, but I modified the code given here https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js to fit my use and it worked!

Comment: Looks like you have to import the function and return the action for it to work.

Comment: @ChiragKalra, can you tell what functions you had imported

Comment: @Shubh we have to export our functions as shown here https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't export my function `listenForNotificationRequests()` but called it only once at the end of the script.
Which is why it didn't show up on the Firebase Console.

I fixed this by simply exporting the function like this

```
exports.sendFollowerNotification = listenForNotificationRequests;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how big of a difference this makes, but in the Firebase admin set up page https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup, it is mentioned that for Cloud Functions, the following line is sufficient for initialisation:-

```
var firebase = require('firebase-admin');
firebase.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

So, if you're going by the book, you may replace the initialisation line in your code with the one above and try running it again.

Comment: Thanks Rohan, but I tried using some other code, and it worked fine for me

Comment: @ChiragKalra could u plz share ur answer to this problem

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js
this code worked for me